# Very Strange iOS 64-Bit vs. 32-Bit Issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8, 32bit-64bit

I have a strange bug where user touches are not recognized. The iPad acts differently depending on 32/64-bit, and iOS level. Here are the symptoms:

When I open my app, I can navigate around as normal. I then get to a screen where I can tap to make `UIViews` at the location of the touch. But on this screen, the taps aren't recognized. Even taps on buttons outside the `handleTapGestureRecognizer` zone aren't recognized.

This bug only happens on a very specific device and iOS level. It happens on iPad Air and iPhone 5s (and above), both of which use a 64-bit OS. iPad 2, iPad Retina, and iPhone 4s (32-bit OSes) don't have this issue. In addition, it only happens if the device is running pre-iOS 8.1.

What could be the cause of this issue? Where should I even start to debug? The problem needs to be a combination of iOS-level specificities AND 32- vs. 64-bit specificities.

Comment: I suggest you to post a [mcve] so that we can try reproducing it. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than focusing on the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit OS implementations, I would approach this as "My program has a bug. Where is it?" The problem might be something that's not quite right, that accidentally works on 32 bit and fails on 64 bit. It's still a bug either way, you just can't see it in all situations.

Comment: @Pang -- Yeah, the issue is that this is part of a large app that's live in the App Store and would be hard to extract a MCV example without posting the entire app.
@GregHewgill -- That is how I'm currently thinking about it, but I'm not sure how to find out where the touches are going. I've tried a breakpoint in `handlePan` (it doesn't fire), a breakpoint in a custom `touchesBegan` (it doesn't fire). I don't know how else to determine where my tap might be going.

Comment: @rizzes: I guess at that point I'd make sure that `userInteractionEnabled` is correctly turned on for the relevant view(s). Also check for unexpected overlapping views that might be receiving the touch events instead.